# ag-grid - onSortChanged(event) - event.column.getSortIndex() is not reflecting the current value

Tags: sorting, ag-grid

I have implemented Custom Header Component. Upon click of header text, I am calling `this.params.setSort(order, event.shiftKey)` to perform sorting. The sorting works.

But I have onSortChanged event and want to get the sortIndex of that column.
But `event.column.getSortIndex()` returns old sortIndex instead of new value.

```
 onSortChanged(event?) {
   `this.sortIndex = event.column.getSortIndex();` // RETURNS OLD VALUE  
 }
```

Comment: Looks like sortChanged is not the right event to get this update sortIndex. I have instead subscribed to modeUpdated event and it works as required.

Answer (score -1):

Use `getColumnState()`

```
let sortModel = this.props.columnApi.getColumnState().filter((col) => col.sort);

sortModel[0].sortIndex;  // sortIndex
```

Comment: this doesnt explain why this would work better. and also doesnt seem to reflect the correct either. also, code only answers are bad.